# Hall subgroup of a finite group G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a finite group and $x$ is a $p'$ element  of G does this imply that there a Hall $p'$ subgroup of $G$ containing $x$?

Comment: No.   Take $p=2$, $x=(12345)$, and $G=A_5$.  It is true if $G$ is solvable.

Comment: Not all groups have any Hall p-prime subgroups. A5 has no 2-prime subgroup (no subgroup of order 15) but it certainly has elements of odd order.